# check permissions on single folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

The following code works fine for a test site with a just a few folders, but fails on the live site which has around 8000 folders.  How can I just check permissions on a single folder, like `Documents/RootFolder/01/10001`?  Or can I modify the Caml query to just return permissions on 5000 folders at a time?

```
String siteUrl = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/TCS-TestSite";
String userName = "user";
SecureString pwd = ConvertToSecureString("pwd");

ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, pwd);

Web web = ctx.Web;
List test = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
ListItemCollection itemColl = test.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery());
ctx.Load(itemColl, x => x.Include(
                       y => y.RoleAssignments.Include(z => z.Member),
                       y => y.DisplayName));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem item in itemColl)
{
    Console.Write(item.DisplayName + " folder permissions are: ");
    foreach (RoleAssignment role in item.RoleAssignments)
    {
        Console.Write(role.Member.Title + "\t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get permissions for a single folder using [GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfolderbyserverrelativeurl?view=sharepoint-csom) and then get the `RoleAssignments` from the [ListItemAllFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.listitemallfields?view=sharepoint-csom) property on the `Folder` object returned.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Included code below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Callum, this code works.

```
String siteUrl = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/TCS-TestSite";
String userName = "user";
SecureString pwd = ConvertToSecureString("pwd");

ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, pwd);

Web oWeb = ctx.Web;
String folderUrl = "Shared Documents/Documents/RootFolder/01/10001";
Folder sourceFolder = oWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
ctx.Load(sourceFolder);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignments = sourceFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments;
ctx.Load(roleAssignments);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```